# Right justifying with printf

Tags: php, printf

I've got a dictionary where both the keys and values are strings.  I would like to print each key-value pair on its own line with the key left justified and the value right justified.

```
Key1        Test
Key2    BlahBlah
```

Etc...

What's the best way to do this in PHP?  Perhaps a clever way to do with printf?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
printf("%-40s", "Test");
```

The `40` tells printf to pad the string so that it takes 40 characters (this is the padding specifier). The `-` tells to pad at the right (this is the alignment specifier).

See the [conversion specifications documenation](http://docs.php.net/sprintf#refsect1-function.sprintf-parameters).

So, to print the whole array:

```
$max_key_length = max(array_map('strlen', array_keys($array)));
$max_value_length = max(array_map('strlen', $array));

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    printf("%-{$max_key_length}s   %{$max_value_length}s\n", $key, $value);
}
```

Try it here: http://codepad.org/ZVDk52ad

Comment: How did this have 11 up votes? It's wrong, even the specification linked in the post says it's wrong. '-' is for left justification, not right. So who's up voting wrong answers on here? If people are doing this, does it make stackoverflow irrelevant?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about PHP, but in C, the solution to right alignment is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char *Data="hello world";
  printf("%20s\n",Data);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
...$ ./a.out 
         hello world
```

You used to be able to do % 20s too, but in C that's deprecated now. Also, the other answer here is wrong %-20s will left align the text and space out to the right of the printed output.