# Formatting for printf

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

I was given a problem where I was supposed to find factorals of numbers 1 - 20. That I completed, but in the example I was given the console if formatted to be visually appealing. 
Heres the example I was given. The white boxes were there because I was supposed to find the answers myself. So that can be ignored.

[image: Correct Example]

And here's what mine looks like.

[image: My Example]

We haven't been taught anything other than printf so I don't know any alternatives.

Here's my code.

```
long long lngFactoral = 1;
int intNumber = 1;

for (int intIndex = 1; intIndex <= 20; intIndex ++ )
{
    lngFactoral = lngFactoral * intIndex;
    printf("%d! = %lli ", intIndex, lngFactoral);

    intIndex++;

    lngFactoral = lngFactoral * intIndex;
    printf("                          %d! = %lli \n", intIndex, lngFactoral);
}
```

Comment: What about `printf("%-2d! = %-20lli ", intIndex, lngFactoral);`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380868/right-justifying-with-printf   or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276827/string-padding-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set field width in printf. You will have to specify the width with the format specifier using the integer value that sets the field width. For example, "%5d" or "%10d".

If the value to be printed is shorter than this number, the result is padded with blank spaces.

In your case your case you can modify your `printf` in the following manner:

First `printf` statement:

```
 printf("%2d! = %20lli ", intIndex, lngFactoral);
```

Second `printf` statement:

```
printf("   %2d! = %20lli \n", intIndex, lngFactoral);
```

`%2d` on the left-hand side is because you are finding the factorial of only 2 digit numbers, so we are going to set the field width 2.

Similarly,`%20d` is used on the right-hand side because the factorial of the largest number 20 is never going to exceed 20 digits.